# flip an image when onClick event

Tags: reactjs, css

In order to implement some features in my react app I need to flip an image in a grid horizonaly when the user choose it with onClick event.

I've readed regarding states in react , and noticed that this is what I need.
When onClick event, flip the image.

The follwing code isn't working well.
The `isExpanded` working fine, but the image in the grid isn't fliping.

What I'm doing wrong ?

I have initiated the `isExpanded` to `false` in my constractor.

```
 handleToggle(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isExpanded: !this.state.isExpanded,
    })


render() {
    const {isExpanded } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        className={`image-root ${isExpanded ? 'image-flip' : ''}`}
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${this.urlFromDto(this.props.dto)})`,
          width: this.state.size + 'px',
          height: this.state.size + 'px'
        }}
        >
        <div>
        <FontAwesome className="image-icon" onClick={(e)=> 
         this.handleToggle(e)} name="arrows-alt-h" title="flip"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The *.scss* code:

```
.image-root {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid white;

  > div {
    visibility: hidden;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: pre;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  &:hover > div {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .image-icon {
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 3px;

    &:hover {
      color: white;
      border-color: white;
    }
  }
 .image-flip {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
```

Comment: It may be easier to discard the template literal and just use a regular ternary operator.  `className={ isExpanded ? 'image-root image-flip' : 'image-root'}` should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've changed it to the above, but still no action.

Comment: Can you inspect the image to confirm if the class is in fact changing?

Comment: Yes, the class changed to `class="image-root image-flip"`

Comment: What other CSS do you have on the image? Something must be conflicting with it, I made a working demo [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/mYJpwd)

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192981/discussion-between-ido-segal-and-rutherford-wonkington).

Comment: Rutherford, I have another question, now the flip is working fine, but the hover buttons flipped as well. how do I can avoid this behavior ?

Comment: If you have the image set up as the background image on a div, the entire div will flip, including anything within it.  If you want to flip only the image you may want to use an img element within a container, or take the icon out of the div and wrap both in another container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was accured due to the `image-flip` css was in the wrong scope.
I just move the `image-flip` css out of the `image-root` scope.
Thanks.